# System can't find: mchange-commons-java-0.2.11

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot project that using connection pool. It work properly in my computer but when my colleague pull the code from git then try to run. It thrown an error as below:

```
2018-02-28 14:49:24.527  WARN 11856 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/ABC/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2/mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ABC\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:288) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

I also tried to add dependency for **mchange-commons-java-0.2.11**, but it still doesn't work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

If you faced or had experiences about it, please leave me a comment/idea.

Your advice or suggestions will be much appreciated and welcomed!

Comment: Delete the `.m2` directory and run `clean install`

Comment: Thanks Malik, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Manually copy `mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar` from its location to C:\Users\ABC\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\ and try. Yes, I know this is dirty way but it will help us whether the problem is because of missing jar in the above location.

Comment: Yes, I tried this way. It worked as you said. But we need to discover where is the root cause and a general way to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

From the **StandardJarScanner** javadoc:

> The default JarScanner implementation **scans the WEB-INF/lib** directory
> followed by the provided classloader and then works up the classloader
> hierarchy. This implementation is sufficient to **meet the requirements
> of the Servlet 3.0 specification** as well as to provide a number of
> Tomcat specific extensions. The extensions are:
>
> - Scanning the classloader hierarchy (enabled by default) Testing all files to see if they are JARs (disabled by default)
> - Testing all directories to see if they are exploded JARs (disabled by default)
> - All of the extensions **may be controlled via configuration**.

To disable that particular jar from being scanned at startup you can add this spring boot specific property:

```
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*mchange-commons-java*.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the c3p0 .jar file with the wrong Class-Path:

[image]

Comment: what is correct class path? could not see your image.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your spring boot transitive dependency is referring the wrong 
mchange-commons-java. From your error, it's searching for path  .m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar. See highlighted c3p0.
Ideally the path has to be com\mchange\mchange-commons-java\0.2.11\mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar.

It seems that mchange-commons-java dependency is conflicted.

When you open pom.xml in eclipse or in any editor, you see dependency hierarchy where it lists all the transitive dependencies. See if there is any mchange-commons-java of c3p0 and if it is there, exclude that dependency. Then your explicit declaration of dependency of mchange-commons-java dependency may work.

Comment: Hi ashi, I checked and it seem does not conflict. And I found that there are 2 folders generated in maven.
That missing file is actually in there, but I don't know why the project can find them.
https://imgur.com/GalxjRT

Answer (score 0):

For me the quartz library was also creating the conflict via the c3po dependency but I've just added this property value to the JVM running arguments for Tomcat skip scanning the jar files not needed:

`-Dtomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*.jar`

(if you add this to your catalina.properties files, just remove the `-D` prefix)

> If you need the jar scanning, you may exclude only the offending jars instead of `*.jar`